# PayPal + RESTful API + WebHooks + Self Signed Certificates

Tags: api, ssl, paypal

I've been working with the REST API for PayPal and I'm able to get the sales, refunds, etc processed without an issue. But I am having an issue with the webhooks.

I have a webhook configured in sandbox and it never posts the information to the webhook URL (doesn't even attempt to according to the access logs).

Since wbehooks required https I was wondering if there is an issue with using self signed certificates with webhooks?  It's the only thing I can think of to prevent PayPal from accessing the URL short of PayPal's sandbox being glitchy (I know, that NEVER happens).  I can get IPN to work with the self signed but iirc SSL isn't a requirement for IPN.

HELP, PLEASE...

~ Wranorn

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hey this is Avi from PayPal. Self signed certs should not be working for webhooks, if you want to test out a different endpoint you can use something like ngrok to test it locally. Otherwise it would be useful to know debug id received from PayPal for the payment execution call. There are some existing service issues for webhooks on Sandbox currently that could be contributing to this, and those are being actively worked on.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's part of my problem.  There is no debug information either on my server or available from the sandbox to troubleshoot exactly what the issue might be.  Any idea if I'm just missing something on PayPal's side as far as debugging?

Comment: What particular event from https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/rest-webhooks-overview/#events are you trying to get a notification for? e.g. If you are trying to get a notification for PAYMENT.AUTHORIZATION.CREATED , the way to debug it would be to provide the PayPal-Debug-Id that is send back in the response header after doing an [execute on the approved PayPal payment](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#execute-an-approved-paypal-payment). Currently, webhook support is there for PayPal payments only.

Comment: PayPal payments meaning using the redirection urls for the end user so they log into the paypal system (I'm assuming).  In that case I'll have to rely on IPN.  Thank You!  Just needed to know which direction to go.

Comment: [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) is the only way I've found to test webhooks using localhost.