# Paypal Sandbox Not Sending Webhook or IPN Notifications

Tags: ruby, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-adaptive-payments

I'm using the PayPal Adaptive Payments Ruby SDK (https://github.com/paypal/adaptivepayments-sdk-ruby)

What I want to do is send User A an email requesting a PayPal deposit on behalf of User B.

I'm generating a `pay_key` and redirect URL no problem to PayPal's site. There, User A can login and pay User B through PayPal's site.

The problem is that I need to know when the transaction has completed. One method is to wait for User A to be redirected to a URL on my site, but this isn't very reliable. I'd rather use IPN or Webhooks to receive the notification.

In Sandbox mode, the IPN or Webhooks aren't being triggered, so I can't really test (simulator won't help).

Also, looking at the docs, I am not sure how to map the transaction ID back to the original Pay Key either so that I can tell User A has paid.

Answer (score 0):

I found here ([PayPal + RESTful API + WebHooks + Self Signed Certificates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26643041/paypal-restful-api-webhooks-self-signed-certificates)) knowing that webhook won't work with self signed cert. Are you using self signed cert. for SSL?